# Problem on my project. Getting 404 on my CSS file

Tags: html, css, cs50

In my HTML, I wrote

```
<link href ="project.css" rel ="stylesheet">
<style>
   body, html {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   }
</style>
<title>Page1</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="bg"></div>
</body>
```

In my CSS, I wrote:

```
 .bg {
    /* The image used is edited from original World Table Tennis logo */
     background-image: url("WTT.jpeg");
    /* Full height */
     height: 100%;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to insert the image that I uploaded to my VS Code into my page, which is why I used CSS. Unfortunately, when I use Flask run, I get `GET /project.css HTTP/1.0" 404`.

I originally had `my.bg` on my HTML page, but I received `GET /WTT.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404`. So I moved it to my CSS file. I haven't done the curse in a couple of months, so I'm a bit lost, especially when using images.
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0bcz.png)

Comment: Just out of interest have you tried removing the spaces between `link` and `="project.css"`?

Comment: Can you show what your folder tree looks like?

Comment: Where have you stored your CSS and image files?

Comment: @MeltingDog yes, no improvement.

Comment: My CSS file and html are all listed under a folder labelled project, html is in a sub category/folder :templating like what I remember learning. My image is not in the folder? I didn't figure I would have to, and I did that and tested, but to no effect

Comment: @AHaworth main folder is called project :contains app.py and the image file, as well as a sub folder: templates, containing two html pages and my css. I've tested simply moving the css outside the sub folder, but it seems like a no go

Comment: FYI: I think I was supposed to put my css in a static folder, so I did?But theres no difference. I think its something overall that is not working as I tested using other components of my css file that are also not working with my html

Comment: Can you upload a picture of your filestructure?

Comment: @Kablam added it at the end of my post

Comment: Aye, in that case, your css is on another level than your .html file is. With ../ in the filename, you can go up a level, so if you use `<link href ="../static/project.css" ...` you first move down into the /project folder, then back up into /static.

Comment: @Kablam omg bro thank you so much:). However, the rest of my CSS like fonts are not loading on the screen. My css consists of .centred
{
    text-align: center;
} and I use <p class="centred"></p> which is not implementing it

Comment: @S0ulzz, most browsers have some kind of developer tools built in, try right clicking an element on your page and choose "inspect", it'll make troubleshooting much easier. For the basis of CSS and why things work the way they do, there are many tutorials out there that will explain way better than I could.

Comment: @Kablam yep thank you once again bro. Didn't notice that ../ was sort of a redirection. But much of my current issues have been resolved, rly appreciate it

Answer (score -2):

**Befor**
href ="project.css" rel ="stylesheet"

**After**
href="project.css" rel="stylesheet"

remove spaces on both sides and check

Comment: No difference but thanks though